# How to reference resource bundle?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, resourcebundle

I am creating a Java GUI and want to use a resource bundle to store all of my sql queries in a .properties file. My class for loading the resource bundle is in a package in the src/main/java folder where the .properties file is in the src/main/resources folder:

[image]

I keep getting a missing resource exception. What am i missing?

Other similar questions say to add the folder to the build path, which it is:
[image: build path]

This is my call to get the resource bundle:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.properties` file extension to form a correct basename as indicated by the [official ResourceBundle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html)

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dominiondatabase");
```

Comment: Genius! Glossed over a tiny detail.